# Are there Places of Power that are missable?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I was under the assumption that the Places of Power were not missable, as they are mostly tied to simply finding them in the world. Some required you to be at a certain part of the story quest to be reachable, but even if they were missed during said quest, you could seemingly go back and find them for the skill point afterwards. However (late story quest spoilers):

> In the quest [Through Time and Space](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Through_Time_and_Space), there is a Place of Power in the second location. It is the locale after the Ddiddiwedht Desert, the first you are separated from Avallac'h, with the poison gas. The Place of Power is pointed out, and told how to navigate to, in this [Eurogamer article](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2015-05-18-the-witcher-3-walkthrough-3696?page=31). However, it doesn't appear on the map, and could be missed depending on how you progress through the poisoned, lowlands areas. Obviously, if you don't activate this Place of Power before moving on to the next world, you will permanently miss it.

Are there any other instances of permanently missable Places of Power, due to either story, quest, or geographic limitations?

Answer (score 7):

**Note: Since I didn't play through the blood and wine addon yet, I can't 100% confirm that there are no missable places in that one!**

There are only a few places in Witcher 3 which you can't revisit:

- The Isle of Mist
- The area where you'll be ported in one of the last quests in the hearts of stones dlc
- The different worlds which you travel through

The first two do not contain any places of power and it is possible to revisit every other area of the game after you've completed it. So no, there are no places of power you can miss besides that one.

**EDIT:**
I finally had time to play through the game again and this time, I completely ignored the skellige quest, which will put Brans son on the throne. If you do that, the place of power in the basement will be unreachable for you!

Comment: What about the place of power in the basement of the castle during the Kings gambit quest?  Can you still get there if you don't side with a particular person?

Comment: There is one area in Blood and Wine that you can't return to but I don't think anyone has found a Place of Power there (difficult to be sure as there is no map).

Comment: @lI You mean after the basement is set on fire and you have to escape through that secret tunnel? It'll always be open if you help cerys or hjalmar, but I'm not sure what happens if you completely skip the quest. But I think - think - that you can open the tunnel manually. Most places in the witcher universe can be opened without the specific quests

Comment: @YUNOWORK will it be open if you help Hjalmar? I thought only Cerys unlocks the basement.  Granted I've never helped Hjalmar so I wouldn't know.

Comment: @lI I'm kinda sure that the basement will be open even tho you help Cerys. At least I remember getting that place of power on my playthrough where i helped hjalmar.

Comment: The an Craite basement place of power is missable if you ignore the quest, i.e. if you decide to put king Bran's son on the throne. I had this outcome in one of my games

Comment: @Alien-47 I remember getting to that place even tho I helped hjalmar in a playthrough. It was not during the quest, but I was able to get to it after I played through the game and was finishing everything on the map.

Comment: @YUNOWORK I also think that after this quest (King's Gambit), it locks up the basement again. I helped Cerys, and after going back to request help during another quest and promptly getting lost, I remember the basement door being locked. I don't know how you'd miss it, the Place of Power in the basement is (IIRC) along a narrow corridor where it is practically impossible to not see. However, if somehow you rushed through it and didn't stop to activate it, I'm not sure there's a way back into the basement outside of that quest.

Comment: @YUNOWORK no-no, there are 3 options in this quest - help Cerys, help Hjalmar and the 3rd one - just go away, abandon the quest. Only the 3rd option lets you make Svanrige Bran the king, and that's the option that never allows you into the cellar, it remains locked

Comment: @Alien-47 If you help noone, that might be true, I didn't check that. But you can get the place of power if you help either cerys or hjalmar, thats something I'm sure of